# Phantom Js on apache

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, backbone.js, seo

I made a js app.
But now I want this app to be SEO friendly.

I was wondering if somebody already had set-up a crawlable webpage 
build on apache with backbonejs (maybe with help from php and .htaccess files, or with phantomjs)

I found [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/), [brombone](http://www.brombone.com/) 
but those services are not free.

Are there tings I could do to set it up quickly myself?
Or should I use a payed service?

Answer (score 0):

You can try node package [seoserver](https://npmjs.org/package/seoserver)

```
https://npmjs.org/package/seoserver
```

Comment: But this is on a node enviroment

Comment: @RobbieBardijn phantomjs is also on node environment as it is javascript. How do you run phantomjs ?